# Reading the body of a 400 response?

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am trying to read the body of a 400 response with the `rest-client` gem.  The problem is that `rest-client` responds to 400 by throwing it as an error, so I can't figure out any way to get the body text.

Here's the motivating example.  Consider this call to the facebook graph API:

```
JSON.parse(RestClient.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=#{access_token}"))
```

If the `access_token` is expired or invalid, facebook does two things:

1. Returns a 400 Bad Request HTTP response
2. Returns JSON in the response body with more info, like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "The access token could not be decrypted",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}
```

Because 400 response raises an Error, I can't figure out how to get the body of the response.  That is, eg, if I run the GET request above in curl or in my browser, I can see the body, but I can't figure out how to access it in restclient.  Here's an example:

```
begin
  fb_response = JSON.parse(RestClient.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=#{access_token}"))
rescue => e
  # 400 response puts me here
  # How can I get the body of the above response now, so I can get details on the error?
  # eg, was it an expired token?  A malformed token?  Something else?
end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [`rest-client` documentation](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#exceptions-see-wwww3orgprotocolsrfc2616rfc2616-sec10html):

> **Exceptions**
>
> for other cases, a RestClient::Exception holding the Response will be raised; a specific exception class will be thrown for known error codes

```
begin
  RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource'
rescue => e
  e.response
end
```

You can rewrite your code like:

```
body = begin
  RestClient.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=#{access_token}")
rescue => e
  e.response.body
end
fb_response = JSON.parse(body)
```

Or just use [RestClient::Exception#http_body](http://rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client/RestClient/Exception#http_body-instance_method) to get the response body from the exception. (It's just a shortcut).